# Calculating center beam for purlins on porch roof

Tags: roof, porch, load, span-tables

I'm building a porch roof as seen in the picture below. The blue boards will be 2x6x12 on 24" centers. Knowing this, how do I determine the size of the red boards? I do plan on doubling each red board as well.

Overall roof is 11', posts are 10' from building wall.

[image: example]

Comment: Location will help.  Snow and wind loads need to be known.  I would turn it around so the blue boards were on beams front and back, but that is me.

Comment: Located near Memphis, TN. I'm trying to maximize headroom without changing the pitch, this design seems to best accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum load 2x6’s at 24” oc can support is about 30 lbs. per square foot (psf), depending on the species and grade.

Therefore, the load transferred to the center red beam is a maximum of 30 psf x 12’ (6’ on each side of the beam is transferred to the beam) = 360 lbs. per linear foot (plf). If the posts are 10’ from the building, the red beam spans 10’ and needs to be a 4x8 depending on the species and grade. (I used SPF.)

The blue beams on the end support half what the center beam support and 2-2x6’s can be used there.

However, the critical criteria is going to be the connections. You’ll need 4-16d nails at the center support (end nailed) and 2-16d nails (end nailed) for the end conditions. (Or you can use metal clips.)

I think the reason @crip659 suggested rotating the direction of the joists and beams is because 1) visually the space will appear as one and not divided into two, and 2) the 2x6’s can support more load and still use a 4x8 for the beam spanning from post to post.

Comment: I don't think my picture was clear enough. This is 2 sections of roofing, each 12'x11' making a total of 24'x11'. In this example, the center beam is 2-ply, while the end beams are single boards. Purlins are to be attached using joist hangers.

Comment: A 4x8 is acceptable for the middle beam, but double 2x8’s are not strong enough. You’d need to upsize to 2-2x10’s. Joist hangers are acceptable.

Comment: Thanks, Lee, this has been super helpful. Do you happen to have a source I can reference for future projects?

Comment: No reference available. Each beam is individually calculated.